# How to efficiently lookup items in QAbstractTableModel::data?

Tags: c++, qt, model

From what I have seen, Qt documentation and majority of examples online assume that we are happy with (column, row)-based lookup in `data()`. But what If my table is based on a custom structure? For instance let's have:

```
struct MyDrive
{
    QString serialNo;
    QString user;
    QString pc;
    QString ipAddress;
    QString category;
};
```

where `serialNo` is the key. So any operation **from outside** (imagine the model having implemented a listener) uses it for removing/modifying an item, making `QMap` as an ideal candidate.

But how to connect this structure with `QModelIndex`'s data? `QAbstractTableModel::data` asks for data with (column,row) as key, making it more suitable for `QVector<QVector>>` or something similar (somewhere I read I should avoid using containers with non-constant access time (like map) in `data()`).

I can imagine using, well, a map with `QModelIndex` as key and `serialNo` as value, which would be used as key to my (serialNo-based) map but this looks very inefficient -- `QModelIndex` addresses concrete entry (serialNo, user, pc, ...) after all so we'd be duplicating the same item over and over again. I was also thinking about having a `<serialNo, MyDrive*>` map but this is just a workaround to an ugly design decision.

I can't believe I'm the first one with this scenario, so how is it usually solved?

Comment: You'll need to subclass QAbstractItemModel and override index. Use createIndex and pass a pointer to your data structure

Comment: @linuxfever Yeah, in the meantime I have figured that out but still... what would you pass to the pointer? Whole structure? For every column? Seems a bit inefficient to me...

Comment: Can you describe how you expect your table view to look like? Is it a single row with user, pc, ipadress and category as columns?

Comment: @linuxfever exactly (plus the serial number). It's no issue with presenting the records but working with them. To me it looks like that I have to choose whether I want an efficient way to modify them or presenting them, but not both.

Comment: I'm preparing an answer for you. I assume you have many instances of MyDrive. How are these stored? vector<MyDrive>?

Comment: I have updated my question -- I'm sorry not being specific about the modification step -- it's being updated from outside, not from the table.

Comment: You say `QMap` would be an ideal candidate. A `QMap<QString, MyDrive*>` seems like a reasonable solution to me. Why do you say this is a workaround to an ugly design decision and what is the ideal structure you want to use to represent your underlying model? (the more details the better)

Comment: @linuxfever yeah, that surely works. What I don't like on it is that I still point to the same item for every column -- so QModelIndex(row, <whatever>) will still point to the same item and I will need to access those properties manually. But now as I think about it, there's hardly a better way to do it. So perhaps you are right and this is the correct answer. Feel free to update yours, I'll accept it.

Comment: It took me a while but I think I can now see your point regarding QMap<QString, MyDrive*>. You basically have no direct way to go from <row,col> to the serialNo. Let me think about it a bit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238851/discussion-between-linuxfever-and-miro-kropacek).

Answer (score 0):

You can use QAbstractItemModel::match to find items by serial
[qt help](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#match)
And enter all the necessary data into the table. This will allow you not to use containers, but how efficient is this a question...

Second solution is subclass AbstractItemModel [Reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference). Now you can do what you want and use any container by implementing data() function.